# How to set default year in chartjs timeseries charts? Why is default year in chart.js version 3 2001?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, chart.js

I've data and chart options coming from Backend. I'm trying to set up charts based on the min/max values provided. Now these min/max values, at times, should match the same as that of the values for chart e.g.,

```
data : [{x: "Feb '21", y: 302}, {x: "Mar '21", y 123}]
```

and the options hold :

```
options: {
   scales: {
      x:{
         max:"Jul '21",
         min:"Feb '21",
         time: {
          unit: 'month',
          displayFormats: {
            month: MMM 'YY
          }
      }
   }
}
```

So when it renders the chart, it generates the ticks on x-axis as `Feb '01, Mar '01,...,'Jul '01`

Can someone please help me understand, why does the default year falls back to 2001?
How can I modify that to accept 2021 by deafult?

This happens only in when the labelFormat is `MMM 'YY`. The other kind of formats understands that it is 2021.

Comment: shouldnt it be `month: 'MMM YY'` instead of `month: MMM 'YY` ?